# MySQL SUM() on identical cells in different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a database on which I run the following query:

```
SELECT products.name AS 'Product', 
products_used.amount * procedures_perf.amount AS 'Total' 
    FROM products_used 
    INNER JOIN procedures ON procedures.pr_id = products_used.pr_id 
    INNER JOIN products ON products.p_id = products_used.p_id 
    INNER JOIN procedures_perf ON procedures_perf.pr_id = products_used.pr_id 
    INNER JOIN hospitals ON hospitals.h_id = procedures_perf.h_id 
    WHERE hospitals.h_id = "20001"
```

This produces the following excerpt:

```
Product     Total
-----------------   
retractor   402
EB          402
EB          0
retractor   105
EB          0
```

So there are a number of procedures, which all use a specific set of products. I am trying to select the amount of total products used, whereas it is giving me a list of each product used per procedure. The outcome I would want is this:

```
Product     Total 
-----------------
retractor   507
EB          402
```

I have tried to use SUM() on the multiplication, but it keeps grabbing the total of all products. The only solution I could find online is one where the "Product" field would have to be listed in an IF-clause, but I do not want to hardcore the product names in an IF-statement, as it is an ever expanding list. I am probably overlooking something really obvious...

JUST TO BE CLEAR: Group by products.name is not adding up the total values, it just takes the first value it gets. SUM(x * y) suggestion is throwing out an obscenely large number.

Comment: You may want to read up on `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You select 3 columns, but only show 2 in your output. Hard to know what you're asking for then...

Comment: Hint:  `sum(products_used.amount * procedures_perf.amount)` . . .` group by Product`.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson if I GROUP BY the Product, it will not SUM() the Totals of these products.

Comment: @jarlh Sorry, the Procedures column is irrelevant in this case. I do not want to use that in the SUM() or filter on it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That gives me a ridiculously high number that doesn't match. I've tried it.

Comment: @RudyvanSloten Your query is wrong. As in select statement you are projecting 3 columns and in your output only 2 columns you have shown.

Comment: @FallAndLearn I have corrected the post, I merely didn't paste the column here given it is irrelevant to the formula, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use of group by-

```
SELECT products.name AS 'Product', 
SUM(products_used.amount * procedures_perf.amount) AS 'Total' 
    FROM products_used 
    INNER JOIN procedures ON procedures.pr_id = products_used.pr_id 
    INNER JOIN products ON products.p_id = products_used.p_id 
    INNER JOIN procedures_perf ON procedures_perf.pr_id = products_used.pr_id 
    INNER JOIN hospitals ON hospitals.h_id = procedures_perf.h_id 
    WHERE hospitals.h_id = "20001" 
GROUP BY products.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT product, SUM(total) as total
FROM tablename
GROUP BY product;
```

After changing your whole query

```
SELECT products.name AS 'Product', 
SUM(products_used.amount * procedures_perf.amount) AS 'Total' 
FROM products_used
INNER JOIN procedures ON procedures.pr_id = products_used.pr_id 
INNER JOIN products ON products.p_id = products_used.p_id 
INNER JOIN procedures_perf ON procedures_perf.pr_id = products_used.pr_id 
INNER JOIN hospitals ON hospitals.h_id = procedures_perf.h_id 
WHERE hospitals.h_id = "20001" 
GROUP BY products.name;
```

Comment: Should `procedures.name` even be there? It's not in the desired result in the query.

Comment: Yes. This is what I commented in his question. He has shown 3 columns in his output which is not abiding by his query. I have shown him the logic using GROUP BY.

Comment: For some reason, it does not add the totals up correctly. I get a number far larger than the actual amount.

Comment: First run the correct query without group by and show us the result you are getting.

Comment: Run this first and show the result `SELECT products.name AS 'Product', 
SUM(products_used.amount * procedures_perf.amount) AS 'Total' 
FROM products_used
INNER JOIN procedures ON procedures.pr_id = products_used.pr_id 
INNER JOIN products ON products.p_id = products_used.p_id 
INNER JOIN procedures_perf ON procedures_perf.pr_id = products_used.pr_id 
INNER JOIN hospitals ON hospitals.h_id = procedures_perf.h_id 
WHERE hospitals.h_id = "20001" `

Comment: @FallAndLearn 

    retractor
    115296